# reading multiple lines of text until blank line

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I'm working on a program that gets the user to enter text until the program reads a blank line. So far, I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    string text; 
    cout << "Enter Your Text: " << endl; 
    getline(cin,text);
    cout << "Text" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But, this only outputs my text as a line and not individual lines, like I would like it to.  And then there is the part when it reads a blank line that signifies the end of the user input.

I read that `getline()` gets all user input, but how do I display it as individual lines?

I read that I may have to use a tokenizer, but I am confused as to how they work, and how you actually write one. I was thinking of using a vector, or some kind of array, but vectors are the only ones I am sort of familiar with.

And I'm not quite sure how to get the program to stop at a blank line. I was thinking maybe a `while` loop, but what would go in the parenthesis, and how would that be combined with getting the user input?

What I'm basically trying to figure out is how to modify my code to output the user input as lines rather than one whole statement, and to stop getting user input when the user enters a blank line.

Comment: Whoever told you that `getline` gets all user input was wrong. As it's name suggests `getline` reads **one** line of input. So your code needs a loop where you read one line at a time (with `getline`) until the user enters a blank line.

Comment: You are massively overthinking this, vectors, tokenizers etc are not needed. Just read the input one line at a time and stop the loop when the input is a blank line

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> text; 
    std::string line; 

    std::cout << "Enter Your Text: " << std::endl; 

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty())
        text.push_back(line); 

    std::cout << "You entered: " << std::endl; 

    for (auto &s : text)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```